# OnClick not working, "Could not execute method for android:onClick" What is it?

Tags: java, android

It's the simplest code, everything looks right except the onclick refuses to work. Perhaps it is the most basic of errors, but I just cannot spot it.

```
package mymedicareappcom.****;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
}

public void buttonLogin(View view) {




}
```

Comment: read a little further in the error, there is more to it.

Comment: Which is the method to be executed in onClick? Check you XML. android:clickable="true" should be included

Comment: I've checked the XML, they are correct. I even have an old app I was making, open and the onClick's are formatted and coded in the same way. Surely I'm missing something obvious

Comment: heres the XML for both, more or less the same apart from id's

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BSignUp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/BLogin"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="buttonRegister"
        android:clickable="true"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your context is set to your activity in tools name space in layout.
Make sure the classes you're opening in intent  are registered activities in your package.

Comment: That is an excellent point, checking that now

Comment: Upon checking I noticed they weren't included in the manifest folder

Comment: So they couldn't be accessed due to not being registered I guess. Which is probably why you cannot start them using your intent. This intent is for starting registered in manifest activity which is compiled into your project.

Comment: Yup, I'm just a dope

Comment: We're all dopes sometimes. And it's always with the easiest of things right in front of our eyes. Good luck. You can mark as answered.